# JasperReports not work on Grails 2.4: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory

Tags: java, grails, groovy, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I'm using grails version 2.4.0 and *JasperReports* plugin: 1.9.0 (also tried version jasper-1.10.0-SNAPSHOT) but when I export to pdf I got errors.

When I first start project, I run export report and got this message

```
org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap
```

After that when I try again and it shows this error.

```
Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory
```

It seems to be in competitive with version 2.4.0 because it works on 2.2.4

Here my code

In controller

```
def results = new ArrayList()
        def reportFolder = "${grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource('reports').file.absolutePath}"
        def sep = System.getProperty('file.separator')
        def app = Applicant.get(2)
        results.add(
                first: app.firstName,
                middle: app?.middleInitial,
                last: app.lastName,
                ssn: app.ssn,
                workPhone: app.workPhone,
                homePhone: app.homePhone
        )
reportService.exportPDFReport("${reportFolder}${sep}aaa.jrxml", results, params, response)
```

In service (note that service named: reportService)

```
def exportPDFReport(String reportPath, results, params, response) {
        def temp_file = File.createTempFile("jasperReport", ".pdf")
        def jrDataSource = new JRMapCollectionDataSource(results)
        JasperReport jReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath)
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, params, jrDataSource)
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, temp_file.absolutePath)
        response.setContentType("application/force-download")
        response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${jReport.name}.pdf")
        response.outputStream << temp_file.newInputStream()
        temp_file.deleteOnExit()
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2.4 or later. you can't combine jasper plugin because it is missing libraries from third part.

It is very easy to resolve that problem. You only need copy these jars to your /lid

- org.apache.commons.collections.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar

Sure 100% it work :-)

Comment: It didn't worked for me, I put them into /lib and rerun the server and still the same. (using grails 2.4.2 and jasper 1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.4 the Holder static classes where removed.  For plugins that still use these classes they cause errors.  I would also try version 2.4.2 instead for grins.  Could you also edit and give us a complete stack trace to help in debugging.